# Scale position absolute div with flex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a div that will be shown when processing a request. I would like that:

1. The web page screen becomes black with some tranparency
2. After the blacking, a div in center must appear scaling from center and with her elements aligned in center.

However when the Javascript is executed the div scales from bottom-right to top-left with the bottom-right corner in the absolute center of the screen.

Is there a way to make the center of the div scale from his center and in the absolute center of the `div_fundo_escuro_total`?

```js
$("#div_fundo_escuro_total").fadeIn({
  duration: 300,
  complete: function() {
    $("#div_info_fundo_escuro").show('scale', {}, 250);
  }
});
```

```css
#div_fundo_escuro_total {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
}

#div_info_fundo_escuro {
  width: 40%;
  min-height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px #444444 solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px 2px #555;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_fundo_escuro_total">
  <div style="width:100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
    <div id="div_info_fundo_escuro">
      Processando this foobar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to use jQuery for the scale? If you were to use a CSS transform scale, you could use `transform-origin` to scale from the centre.

Comment: No, I'm open to any other suggestions for doing this. Thank you

Comment: Then [transform:scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)
[transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)